# Match software programs whose major, minor, and build version did not change

Tags: regex

I'm learning RegEx and doing some online questions. The flags are forced to be `/gm` and JavaScript flavour RegEx.

I'm trying to group various patterns found in some test strings. I am running into a problem where it seems I need to both match and not match a character: clearly, my approach is wrong, but I haven't been able to progress.

The sample strings are:

```
[REMOVE, NOT USED] libaccess-bridge-java
[REMOVE, NOT USED] libaccess-bridge-java-jni
[INSTALL, DEPENDENCIES] libpcsclite1
[HOLD] gir1.0-json-glib-1.0
[HOLD] libjson-glib-1.0-0
[HOLD] xsltproc
[UPGRADE] apache2 2.2.16-6+squeeze7 -> 2.2.16-6+squeeze12
[UPGRADE] apache2-dbg 2.2.16-6+squeeze7 -> 2.2.17-6+squeeze12
[UPGRADE] apache2-mpm-prefork 2.2.16-6+squeeze7 -> 2.2.16-6+squeeze12
[UPGRADE] apache2-utils 2.2.16-6+squeeze7 -> 2.2.17-6+squeeze12
[UPGRADE] apache2.2-bin 2.2.16-6+squeeze7 -> 2.2.17-6+squeeze12
[UPGRADE] apache2.2-common 2.2.16-6+squeeze7 -> 2.2.16-6+squeeze12
[UPGRADE] base-files 6.0squeeze7 -> 6.0squeeze9
[UPGRADE] bind9 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1~squeeze6 -> 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1~squeeze11
[UPGRADE] bind9-host 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1~squeeze6 -> 1:9.7.4.dfsg-1~squeeze11
[UPGRADE] bind9utils 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1~squeeze6 -> 1:9.7.4.dfsg-1~squeeze11
```

There are 5 strings that match the criteria. An example valid match is:

- apache2
- 2.2.16
- 6+squeeze7
- 2.2.16
- 6+squeeze12

The following two test strings are giving me the problem:

```
[UPGRADE] base-files 6.0squeeze7 -> 6.0squeeze9
[UPGRADE] bind9 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1~squeeze6 -> 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1~squeeze11
```

The RegEx I came up with was:

```
^\D\w{7}\D{2}([\w\-\.]+)\s([\d\.\:]+d?f?s?g?)\-?([\d\+\w\~]+)\D{4}(\2)\-?(.*)
```

But this of course gives one incorrect match of:

- base-files
- 6.0**s**
- **queeze7**
- 6.0**s**
- **queeze9**

Attempting to write the RegEx again, I get to here:

```
\D\w+\D\s([\w\-\d\.]+)\s([\d\.\:]+)
```

Which matches:

```
[UPGRADE] base-files 6.0
[UPGRADE] bind9 1:9.7.3.
```

The bind9 string should match with the following groups:

- bind9
- 1:9.7.3.dfsg
- 1~squeeze6
- 1:9.7.3.dfsg
- 1~squeeze11

And so I just can't see how to make sure the 'dfsg' gets matched in Group 2, but that the 's' (or any of the characters) from 'squeeze7' - which should be in Group 3.

I'm obviously missing something here so welcome pointers in the right direction.

Comment: This can be simplified by first isolating the versions.

1) Split it into three fields: `^(\[.+\]) (\S+)( .*)?$`
2) Select only lines with UPGRADE tags.
3) Split the versions on `->`

Then parsing the versions is isolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the pattern a bit more specific, and use a capture group with a backreference `\1` to match up with the version numbers after the  `->`

```
^\[\w{7}]\s([\w.-]+)\s(\d+(?:[.:]\d+)*(?:\.dfsg)?)-?((?:\d+[~+])?\w+)\s->\s(\2)-?(.*)$
```

In parts:

- `^` Start of string
- `\[\w{7}]` Match 7 word chars between square brackets and a space
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[\w.-]+` Match 1+ times either a word char or `.` or `-`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s` Match a space
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\d+(?:[.:]\d+)*` Match 1+ digits and optionally repeat matching `.` or `:` and 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.dfsg)?` Optionally match `.dfsg`
- `)` Close group 2
- `-?` Match optional `-`
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `(?:\d+[~+])?` Optionally match 1+ digits and either `~` or `+`
  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group 3
- `\s->\s` Match `->` between spaces
- `(\2)` Capture **group 4**
- `-?` Match optional `-`
- `(.*)` Capture **group 5**
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UNC2uj/1)

Note that `\w` also matches `\d` and you don't have to escape the `.` and `~` in the character class.

Comment: Thanks for breaking this down so thoroughly. It's the optional matching that I still don't know much about (hence why I struggled to also write a good title for the question!) Do you know of any good online resources to practice further?